# How can I overwrite Excel sheet by win32com in python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm trying to overwrite excel sheet data from A file to B file. For this, I'm using [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/).

```py
import win32com.client
    
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb_dst = excel.ActiveWorkbook
wb_src = excel.Workbooks.Open("source.xlsx")
wb_src.ActiveSheet.Copy(After=wb_dst.ActiveSheet)
```

I finished about copy. But this code made additional sheet to destination file. Basically two files are almost same. So I wanted to copy at same sheet on destination file. But Copy function in pywin32 make automatically before or after active sheet. How can I overwrite it?

Comment: For other tools interacting with Excel, the answer tends to be that you need to create a new sheet (after, for example), remove the sheet before it (saving the name) and then rename the new sheet to have the name of the old one.

Comment: @Grismar - "need" might be a stretch in this case. One can copy the cells on the sheet, as opposed to copying the sheet.

Comment: @BigBen although that's certainly possible, it's unlikely that's actually more efficient - going over the cells and copying them is likely to involve less efficient logic than whatever the built-in logic of Excel itself is to replicate the entire content of the sheet. Of course, if in-place modification of only the cells that change is possible - that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
wb_src.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy(Destination=wb_dst.ActiveSheet.Cells(1))
```

or

```
wb_src.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy(Destination=wb_dst.ActiveSheet.Cells(1))
```

which use the `Copy` method of the `Range` class, different from the `Copy` method of the `Worksheet` class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it is correct! How did u find this method or information? Did you memorize all? or use some site or document? I don't know how I can find the usage?? or list of function.

Comment: You can use the Excel VBA Object Model [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel). Specifically [`Range.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy).